# Search for a value to find the sheet name the value is found in

Tags: excel, vba

I'm not sure how to go about this, but I have two textboxes, one for input, and one for output. I would like to be able to search every worksheets A column for the value, and have the worksheet that it is found on to be posted in the output.
Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds possible to me. What problem did you run into when you tried it?